# < and > change to &lt; and &gt; in HTML code inside a Google Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet script that gets specific values from a sheet and puts them in an array which later is transformed to a HTML table and included in an email.

The code works fine until I try to push the HTML code of the tables in the email template I have as HTML file in Google Apps Script.

This is the specific part of the code which populates the HTML tables:

```
var i,j;
      for(i=0, j=0; i<(eval('array'+a+'[2];').length), j<(eval('array'+a+'[2];').length); i++, j++) {
          result += "<tr>";
          result += "<td>"+eval('array'+a+'[2][j];')+"</td>";
          result += "<td>"+eval('array'+a+'[3][j];')+"</td>";
      }
      
      result += "</tr>";
      result += "</table>";
    
      eval('htmlTable'+a+'.push("'+result+'");')
      var htmlPush = eval('htmlTable'+a)
      
      if(htmlPush != '<table border=1></tr></table>'){
          emailBody += '<div style="text-align:center;float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif">';
          emailBody += htmlPush;
          emailBody += '</div><span>';
      }
```

So the HTML code is placed inside a `div`, one `div` per table.

The log displays correctly for this code:

```
<div style="text-align:center;float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif"><table border=1><tr><td>Locked Proxy</td><td>Fail</td><tr><td>Final Proxy</td><td>Fail</td><tr><td>Final Script</td><td>Fail</td><tr><td>PM</td><td>Fail</td></tr></table></div><span><div style="text-align:center;float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif"><table border=1><tr><td>ME</td><td>Fail</td></tr></table></div><span><div style="text-align:center;float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif"><table border=1><tr><td>Locked Script</td><td>Fail</td></tr></table></div><span>
```

But when I implement this other portion that should replace the "marker" in the HTML template with the actual code, the HTML code changes, specifically the `<` and `>` symbols change to `&lt;` and `&gt;` and this prevents the code from being displayed at all.

---

I found this part of code on this website as I didn't know how to do this specific function:

```
var templ = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('testEmail');
  
  templ.emailBody = emailBody;
  Logger.log(emailBody);
  var emailBody = templ.evaluate().getContent();
```

The log displays:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
        <div style="height: 33px; line-height: 33px; font-size: 31px;">&nbsp;</div><div style="height: 75px; line-height: 75px; font-size: 73px;">&nbsp;</div>
                           
                           
            &lt;div style=&#34;text-align:center;float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif&#34;&gt;&lt;table border=1&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Locked Proxy&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Fail&lt;/td&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Final Proxy&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Fail&lt;/td&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Final Script&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Fail&lt;/td&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;PM&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Fail&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;div style=&#34;text-align:center;float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif&#34;&gt;&lt;table border=1&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;ME&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Fail&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;div style=&#34;text-align:center;float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif&#34;&gt;&lt;table border=1&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Locked Script&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Fail&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;span&gt;                           
                           
    </td>
</tr>
```

Anyone that could help me out with this issue?

Comment: Can I see the values of `testEmail` and `emailBody` for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: For your own sanity, find a solution that does not require using `eval`. Apps Script supports asynchronous loading and client(webpage)-server(Apps Script) interaction. Review the documentation, especially w.r.t. "scriptlets"

Comment: @Tanaike [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8h524tL7/) you can find testEmail.html and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7r83ek1h/) you can find the emailBody values from the log.

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the code you're using and a sample of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), in order to test this?

Comment: @Iamblichus [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TmmXX5eocfDuWTY2lxA5z3l7onOhea98U8i1M32lzo8) a sample of the spreadsheet and [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/as7kofv2/1/) the full code.

Comment: You are using html tags inside printing scriplets (`<?= ... ?>`) which certainly isn't what this is designed for. The content inside printing scriplets should be JS code. You should edit your html template accordingly.

Comment: Also, this code is really messed up and hard to read. I'm having problems understanding what data you want to include in your email. Please consider making your purpose clearer so that people can help you.

Comment: @Iamblichus sorry for this, I'm no expert in JS unfortunately. My goal is to copy the result of `emailBody` shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7r83ek1h/) to the existing HTML code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8h524tL7/). Is there any way I can do this - like you said, printing scriptlets are not designed for this.

Comment: @GiacomoViganò I posted an answer that, I think, gives a solution to your issue. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an HTML table dynamically, based on spreadsheet data, you should send the data from the spreadsheet to the HTML, and use [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) there. It could be done the following way:

- First, create a function in your code that will grab the data you want from the sheet. In this case, and based on the information you provided, I think you want to get the data from rows `12-23`, and from columns from `C` till the last one that has data (please modify this accordingly if that's not the case). So such function could be something on the following lines:

```
function getData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Test");
  var firstRow = 12;
  var firstCol = 3;
  var numRows = 24 - firstRow;
  var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn() - firstCol;
  var values = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  return values;
}
```

- This function, and the data returned by it, can in turn be used in your html to create your tables dynamically. I assume you want to create a new table for every column, for each table, you want a row for each existing `Fail` (and each row has to cells, one for the value in `Availability` and one for `QC` (which would also be `Fail`). So in this case you could make two `for` loops that will track the existence of `Fail` cells in each column, and add the corresponding rows to each table:

```
<? var values = getData(); ?>
<? for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) { ?>
  <div style="text-align:center;float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif">
  <table border=1>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i = i + 2) {
    var qc = values[i + 1][j];
    if (qc == "Fail") {
      var availability = values[i][j]; ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= availability ?></td>
        <td><?= qc ?></td>
      </tr>
    <? }
  } ?>
  </table>
  </div>
<? } ?>
```

- Finally, another function would be needed to get the html template, evaluate it and send the email. It could be something like this:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2").getValue();
  var subject = 'IMPORTANT - QC Fail notification for '+ title + ' tracker';
  var emailBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('testEmail').evaluate().getContent();
  var recipient = "recipient_address";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: emailBody
  })
}
```

I'm not sure this was exactly what you wanted, but with this you should get the general of how to create an HTML dynamically, based on the spreadsheet data.

I hope this is of any help.